# Code Example: Waiting for N blocks then running a method?

Tags: javascript, ethers.js, external-api, mocha

I'm new to Javascript and Etherjs. I'm trying to interact with a specific contract in the following way. The contract has two functions, `hi` and `bye`. I want to
first run `contract.hi();`, wait `N` blocks while printing the number of each block to the console, then afterwards run `contract.bye();`. I'm using AlchemyAPI to connect to the testnet.
I'm guessing something like:

```
it("Greeting", async function() {
   await contract.hi();
   
   for(let i = 0; i < N; i++){
      \\What to put here?
      console.log(await ethers.provider.getBlockNumber());
   }

   await contract.bye();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a promise that subscribe to the 'block' events and waits for the correct number of blocks. Read the documentation [Event Emitter Methods](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--event-methods).

A pseudo code would be like:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  provider.on("block", (blockNumber) => {
    if (blockNumber == desiredBlcok) {
      resolve();
    }
  })
});
```